# Only 100% width Footer in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic HTML page where everything is wrapped inside a mainWrapper div and secondWrapper div.

everything is set to 960px size (the pageHeader, the pageContent and pageFooter).

I need to keep everything 960px apart from the pageFooter.

This is my CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
}

#secondWrapper {
        margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    min-width:910px;

}
#mainWrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;

}

#pageHeader {
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 918px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ededed;
    z-index:1000;
    position:relative;


}
#pageContent {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 918px;
    background-image:url(img/map.png); 
    height:600px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px -5px #999, -6px 0px 5px -5px #999;
    z-index:1;

}
#pageFooter {
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 918px;
}

#logo{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:29px;
    background-color:#cb202d;
    width:120px;
    height:110px;
    top: 0;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:center;
    display:block;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    z-index:1000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px grey;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px grey;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px grey;
}

#logoTxt{
    position: relative;
    top:26%;

}

#yourCurrentTime{
    float:left;
    left:220px;
    top:10%;
    position:relative;
    border: 10px solid #1abc9c;
    border-radius:4px;



}

#arrow-down {
    position:absolute;
    width: -23px;
    height: 2px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #1abc9c;
    left: 99px;
    top: 30px;
}

#b {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:10000000;
    left: -59px;
    top: 48px;
    background-color:#333;
    display:none;



}

    div#a:hover div#b {
        display: inline;

    }
        div#a:hover {
            background-color:#eceded;
            cursor:pointer;


    }

            div#divBtn:hover {
            background-color:#4a4a52;
            cursor:pointer;


    }


    div#a{
    width:140px;
    height:47px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 825px;
    top: 0px;
    }


-->
</style>
```

I did try a few solutions found on Google and stackoverflow like this:

```
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
```

but that didn't work for me!

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crf121359/jwgfH/

Comment: can you show us your html code pls? or create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: Are trying to make its width 100% ? If so how is it related to the body's height: 100%?

Comment: Sounds like you've placed your footer within your wrapper. Take it out then check if that works

Comment: @Danield, I did try that too but that would leave a gap on the sides of the footer. i did try the left:0; right:0; bottom 0; as well once the footer was outside of the wrapper but that didn't do anything!

Comment: Please show us the HTML code. You not very clear about what you're trying to do and what's happening

Comment: what do you mean "that would leave a gap on the sides of the footer" if you don't want it centered then use text-align:left;

Comment: The jsfiddle link has been added.

Comment: What do you want it to do? You want a `960px` gap from the `#pageContent`?

Comment: @RenoYeo, No i want everything to stay centered and 960px as they are now apart from the footer which i want it to be 100% width.

Comment: Follow my answer, see if it works for you for centering the objects. As for 'apart from the footer', I'm really not sure what you mean. There's a lot of junk that's separating the stuff. Try `float:left;` to position your elements.

Comment: @RenoYeo, where is your answer?

Comment: I've updated your fiddle . It's working http://jsfiddle.net/jwgfH/1/

Comment: @ItayItai, Please view this image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33o451v&s=5  this is what i see on the right hand side of the footer!!!!

Comment: @Simon Presto: I've updated my answer on this topic with the working link.

Comment: @SimonPresto I deleted it. Its back now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You just need to take your pageFooter outside of the wrapper.
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jwgfH/3/

You should see how it looks here, not inside the little frame:
http://jsfiddle.net/jwgfH/3/show

Comment: if you resize your page and scroll down the page and view the right hand side of the footer, you will see that the footer is not 100% width.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="wrap_inner> 
       <!-- Pwraput here your pageHeader and pageContent -->
   </div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 200px /*footer height*/
}

.wrap_inner {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, when you couldn't even see the source when you posted this. How did you guess that the footer was inside the main wrapper?

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago. :)

Comment: No, this didn't work for me. the reason is because when i resize the browser the footer ends up cut up from the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: @SimonPresto Only because you have `min-width:918px` in your #pageFooter.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 100%;
```

only works if the parent element has a width defined.

Try giving your body element a max-width and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a webpage that's `960px` wide, define it in your `<body>` tag's by placing `width:960px;` in the CSS.

Then, use `width:100%;` in the rest of your elements - only for those that you want to display as `960px`. The rest can be divided by using `width:50%;`, `width:25%;`, which is `50%` of `960px` and `25%` of `960px` respectively.

Also, `height:100%` is negligible, the rest of the elements will automatically define the height of the webpage, as long as you place them correctly.

In short, do this:

```
body {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#secondWrapper {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

...and so on and so forth.

(NOTE: To solve your positioning problem, `float:left` is probably the best way to go. Use it on most of the elements you need to position accurately. If not, the browser will estimate where it will go.)

**AFTER EDIT:**

If you want a `960px` gap between the `#pageContent` and `#pageFooter`, you can always define a margin-top like this:

```
#pageFooter {
    margin-top:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show your html too ? if the parent div or container is having 100% width then it should show the perfect result.

Comment: the jsfiddle has been added.